# Как использовать Русские слова в имени приложения React native IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Есть приложение на react native, пытаясь переименовать проект дабы отображалась имя приложения русскими буквами, выходит предупреждение о использование неизвестных символов.... 
как мне быть кто что посоветует?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте открыть проект в XCode и в настройках General поменять Display Name. См. скриншот:

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Правильный путь для локализации названий приложения в iOS это создание отдельного файлика InfoPlist.strings в котором бы были локализованные названия. Чуть подробнее вот [тут](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/localize-iphone-application-name/)